# Cannot get if statement to work

Tags: shell, csh

Cannot figure out how to get `csh` if statements to work using expect.

This line of code works

`if(4 > 3) echo "4 is greater than 3."`

`$ 4 is greater than 3.`

This line of code does not work

`if (4 > 3) $myvar = 5`

`0: Command not found (i.e. myvar = 0)`

Neither does this one

`if (4 > 3) then $myvar = 5`

`IF: Improper then`

What am I doing wrong?  I preferably need all this on one line or someway to get this into the `send` command for an `expect` script.  Do I use `\` characters if I can't get it on one line?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please state well which language every example line is. In IF statement, sometimes you write "then", sometimes not. "$myvar" has different meanings in different languages. You used too many tags - can we speak about a single language, not shell csh tcl expect?

Comment: @linuxfan I'm guessing that the problem is about using `expect` to automate a remote system that uses `csh`. That would make the tag melange make sense. And it is probably all embedded inside a bash script for extra "fun". The answer will involve getting the quoting right, I bet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing csh syntax with Bourne shell syntax.

You assign variables with `set name = value`. `$name = value` doesn't work (actually, that also doesn't work in Bourne shell, where it's `name=value`).

You only need the `then` for multi-line `if`s. Leave it out for single-line `if`s.

Putting it all together:

```
if (4 > 3) set myvar = 5
```

or:

```
if (4 > 3) then
    set myvar = 5
endif
```