# Having a multi line if condition inside a flock command in a Makefile target

Tags: makefile, csh, flock

I have that following target in my Makefile

```
target: config
     mkdir -p results; \
     cd results; \
     flock . -c ' if ( ! -f "FINISHED_build" )  \
          ln -s $(OUTDIR) output ; \
          rm -rf work; \
          # some other commands \
          touch FINISHED_build; \
          endif ;\
     '
```

although I know that my if condition is evaluation to false and even if I replace the if expression with a 0, the commands inside my if condition are still executed except for the `ln` command.
I expected that my if condition is treated as a single line statement as mentioned here [Cannot get if statement to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567344/cannot-get-if-statement-to-work), so I changed my if condition to be

```
flock . -c ' if ( ! -f "FINISHED_build" ) then  \
```

to add a then. But the behavior doesn't change and I get
if: Improper then. I know that might be related to using backslashes but I am not sure how to fix it. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think your flock command is run with `csh`?  Pretty much everyone and everything uses POSIX sh by default these days.  `csh` is absolutely terrible for scripting.  I doubt you can make this work with csh.

Comment: @MadScientist according to flock man, it will be executed by the current 'shell', based on the value of $SHELL env var.

Comment: My `man flock` does not say anything about using the `$SHELL` environment var.  It just refers to _shell scripts_ and _the shell_.  In any event my comment above stands: csh is horrible for scripting and it will be hard to get this to work, as an inline script: you need to either switch to POSIX sh or else put the csh script into a separate file and invoke it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above in comment, csh is not the ideal tool for scripting. Wrapping it inside a `make` target will make things even more challenging with respect to quoting, using multi line statements, or shell control commands. When entering commands for make rule, they are evaluated by the result shell. Can be very confusing to maintain.

One specific "trap" is the escaped characters (the escaped new lines - in the context of "Makefile", the backquote will sometime used to hide special characters from make, which could have different meaning from escaping them to the shell).

Also note that the multi-statement rule (mkdir ... ; cd ... ; flock ...) will execute the segments unconditionally - the 'cd' and the 'flock' will get executed even if the 'mkdir' failed. Usually better to keep them separate. This does not apply to the 'cd', which must be executed together with the flock

Two possible path: switch to sh (recommended), or stick with csh and use multiple statements

The "simple" solution is to flip to 'sh'. Relatively easy to delimit statements with ';' followed by escaped new-lines. Notice using "sh -c" as the command for flock, and not '-c'.

```
flock . sh -c 'if [ ! -f "FINISHED_build" ] then ; \
          ln -s $(OUTDIR) output ; \
          rm -rf work; \
          # some other commands \
          touch FINISHED_build; \
          fi '
```

If "csh" is desired, consider using csh explictly, The makefile will work even the the executing user that is not using csh by default. In this case, 'csh' consider the input to be 'interactive', and will NOT not allow comments ('#'). If comments are needed, the ':' can be used to hide then from execution.

```
flock . csh -c 'if ( ! -f "FINISHED_build" ) then ; \
          ln -s $(OUTDIR) output ; \
          rm -rf work; \
          : COMMENTS ; \
          touch FINISHED_build; \
          endif '
```

Comment: I switched to sh and your answer worked for me, thanks!

Comment: There aren't any backquotes here?  In any event, make doesn't pay any attention to quotes of any kind; they are just normal characters as far as make is concerned.  But, I did forget that make will preserve backslash/newlines in recipes.